# Glassy eyes and very vocal. What does that mean?

Tags: cats, health, vocalizations

So my boy cat has glassy eyes and has been meowing a lot for the past two days. He has been eating well and is also playing with us. I see darkened wet skin around the corner of his left eye but not the right. His water intake has gone up though. Is this sign of trouble? Is he in pain? I checked him out with a visual inspection and also by lightly pressing his tummy area but he didn't show any reaction to that.

**Edit**: took him to the vet. She said that he does not seem to have any immediate visible problems as such. What's the course of action if we have to determine if he does have diabetes?

Comment: Try visiting a vet

Comment: What type of tests did the vet do? Generally diabetes is diagnosed through blood work. Blood work can also rule out the other common cause of increased thirst (kidney disease)

Answer (score 1):

I'd second Sonevol's comment - taking him to the vet is the best course of action. Glassy eyes and increased water consumption *could* be signs of diabetes (which is  surprisingly common in cats) but that's just a bit of internet-stranger guesswork.